# How to get hidden value from Form when i try to get value on controller value zero always

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x =>x.StreamId, Model.StreamId)     

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.StreamId)
<select id="streamlist" name="list" onchange="DDLStream();">
    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.dtforStream.Rows.Count; i++)
    {  
        <option value="@Model.dtforStream.Rows[i][0]">@Model.dtforStream.Rows[i][1].ToString()</option>
    }
</select>

<p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>


function DDLStream() {
    var k = $("#streamlist").val();
    $("#sid").val(k);
    alert(k);
}
```

Comment: What is the point of this - why are you not just using `@Html.DropDownListFor()` to bind directly to `StreamId`? And you do not have an element with `id="sid"`

Comment: actully berfore i was using   @Html.Hidden("sid", Model.StreamId) but not effect

Comment: That would just create an input with `name="sid"` that would not bind to property `StreamId`. You need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to understand the basics.

Comment: main problem is not that i get selected value into from problem is that i not able to get this value on controller.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
$("#StreamId").val(int.parse($("#streamlist option:selected").val()));
```

Comment: Or just `$("#StreamId").val($("#streamlist').val());`